# The function doesn't get called in windows application and the program is just stuck , but it works perfect in a console application

Tags: c#, winforms

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    static CountdownEvent countdown;
    static int upCount = 0;
    static object lockObj = new object();
    const bool resolveNames = true;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        countdown = new CountdownEvent(1);
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        uint startIP = str2ip(textBox1.Text);
        uint endIP = str2ip(textBox2.Text);
        for (uint currentIP = startIP; currentIP <= endIP; currentIP++)
        {
            string thisIP = ip2str(currentIP);
           // listbox was felt with all addresses
            listBox1.Items.Add(thisIP);

            Ping p = new Ping();
```

I don't know if this is a true calling to the function

```
            p.PingCompleted += new PingCompletedEventHandler(p_PingCompleted);

            countdown.AddCount();
            p.SendAsync(thisIP, 100, thisIP);
        }
        countdown.Signal();
        countdown.Wait();
        sw.Stop();
        TimeSpan span = new TimeSpan(sw.ElapsedTicks);
        listBox1.Items.Add("Took {0} milliseconds. {1} hosts active. "+ sw.ElapsedMilliseconds+" "+ upCount);
    }
```

I think the problem here , when I debug the program this function doesn't execute , and the program gets stuck.

```
     void p_PingCompleted(object sender, PingCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        string ip = (string)e.UserState;
        if (e.Reply != null && e.Reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
        {
            if (resolveNames)
            {
                string name;
                try
                {
                    IPHostEntry hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(ip);
                    name = hostEntry.HostName;
                }
                catch (SocketException)
                {
                    name = "UnKnown";
                }
                listBox1.Items.Add("{0} ({1}) is Alive: ({2} ms) "+ ip+ " "+ name+ " "+ e.Reply.RoundtripTime);
            }
            else
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add("{0} is Alive: ({1} ms)"+ ip+ e.Reply.RoundtripTime);
            }
            lock (lockObj)
            {
                upCount++;
            }
        }
        else if (e.Reply == null)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add("Pinging {0} failed. (Null Reply object?)"+ ip);
        }
        countdown.Signal();
    }
```

This function is used to convert the ip to str.

```
    static string ip2str(uint ip)
    {
        string s1 = ((ip & 0xff000000) >> 24).ToString() + ".";
        string s2 = ((ip & 0x00ff0000) >> 16).ToString() + ".";
        string s3 = ((ip & 0x0000ff00) >> 8).ToString() + ".";
        string s4 = (ip & 0x000000ff).ToString();
        string ip2 = s1 + s2 + s3 + s4;
        return ip2;
    }
```

This function is used to convert to ip.

```
    static uint str2ip(string ip)
    {
        string[] numbers = ip.Split('.');
        uint x1 = (uint)(Convert.ToByte(numbers[0]) << 24);
        uint x2 = (uint)(Convert.ToByte(numbers[1]) << 16);
        uint x3 = (uint)(Convert.ToByte(numbers[2]) << 8);
        uint x4 = (uint)(Convert.ToByte(numbers[3]));
        return x1 + x2 + x3 + x4;
    }
}
}
```

This is the same code but for console application and it work perfect, but I don't know what's wrong when I want to make the same code into a windows application.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net.Sockets;
namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
class Program
{
    static CountdownEvent countdown;
    static int upCount = 0;
    static object lockObj = new object();
    const bool resolveNames = true;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        countdown = new CountdownEvent(1);
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        uint startIP = str2ip("192.168.1.0");
        uint endIP = str2ip("192.168.1.255");
            for (uint currentIP = startIP; currentIP <= endIP; currentIP++)
            {
                string thisIP = ip2str(currentIP);
                Console.WriteLine(thisIP);

                Ping p = new Ping();
                p.PingCompleted += new PingCompletedEventHandler(p_PingCompleted);
                countdown.AddCount();
                p.SendAsync(thisIP, 100, thisIP);
            }
            countdown.Signal();
            countdown.Wait();
            sw.Stop();
            TimeSpan span = new TimeSpan(sw.ElapsedTicks);
            Console.WriteLine("Took {0} milliseconds. {1} hosts active.", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, upCount);
            Console.ReadKey();
    }
    static void p_PingCompleted(object sender, PingCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        string ip = (string)e.UserState;
        if (e.Reply != null && e.Reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
        {
            if (resolveNames)
            {
                string name;
                try
                {
                    IPHostEntry hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(ip);
                    name = hostEntry.HostName;
                }
                catch (SocketException)
                {
                    name = "UnKnown";
                }
                Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1}) is Alive: ({2} ms)", ip, name, e.Reply.RoundtripTime);
            }
           else
            {
               Console.WriteLine("{0} is Alive: ({1} ms)", ip, e.Reply.RoundtripTime);
            }
            lock (lockObj)
            {
                upCount++;
            }
        }
        else if (e.Reply == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Pinging {0} failed. (Null Reply object?)", ip);
        }
        countdown.Signal();
    }
    static string ip2str(uint ip)
    {
        string s1 = ((ip & 0xff000000) >> 24).ToString() + ".";
        string s2 = ((ip & 0x00ff0000) >> 16).ToString() + ".";
        string s3 = ((ip & 0x0000ff00) >> 8).ToString() + ".";
        string s4 = (ip & 0x000000ff).ToString();
        string ip2 = s1 + s2 + s3 + s4;
        return ip2;
    }
    static uint str2ip(string ip)
    {
            string[] numbers = ip.Split('.');
            uint x1 = (uint)(Convert.ToByte(numbers[0]) << 24);
            uint x2 = (uint)(Convert.ToByte(numbers[1]) << 16);
            uint x3 = (uint)(Convert.ToByte(numbers[2]) << 8);
            uint x4 = (uint)(Convert.ToByte(numbers[3]));
            return x1 + x2 + x3 + x4;
     }


}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`Ping`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping(v=vs.110).aspx) class correctly implements the [Event-Based Asynchronous Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228974(v=vs.110).aspx), which means that *you* don't have to deal with the complexities of trying to marshal your event handling code back onto the UI thread.

But what this *also* means is that you cannot *block* the UI thread, as you're doing here:

```
countdown.Wait();
```

You need to make sure that `button1_Click` actually returns, to free up the UI thread, so that the event handler can run. This may mean you need to restructure some of your other code (maybe placing more of it inside the `PingCompleted` handler, making some more/different variables static and probably eliminating the `CountdownEvent` entirely)

---

Rough sketch of what I'd change:

```
static int countdown;
static Stopwatch sw;
```

Then:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    countdown = 0;
    sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    uint startIP = str2ip(textBox1.Text);
    uint endIP = str2ip(textBox2.Text);
    for (uint currentIP = startIP; currentIP <= endIP; currentIP++)
    {
        string thisIP = ip2str(currentIP);
       // listbox was felt with all addresses
        listBox1.Items.Add(thisIP);

        Ping p = new Ping();
        p.PingCompleted += new PingCompletedEventHandler(p_PingCompleted);

        countdown++;
        p.SendAsync(thisIP, 100, thisIP);
    }
}
```

And then at the bottom of `PingCompleted`:

```
    else if (e.Reply == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Pinging {0} failed. (Null Reply object?)", ip);
    }
    countdown--;
    if(countdown==0)
    {
        sw.Stop();
        TimeSpan span = new TimeSpan(sw.ElapsedTicks);
        listBox1.Items.Add("Took {0} milliseconds. {1} hosts active. "+ 
                            sw.ElapsedMilliseconds+" "+ upCount);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you help me with that , i tried so much but nothing work .

Comment: @AmeenAbuBaker - I've added a sketch to the bottom of what I think I'd change.